# How to determine linear acceleration using an accelerometer?

Tags: reference-frames, acceleration, electronics, gyroscopes

I have a implemented an accelerometer, a gyro and a Magnetometer in Raspberry Pi.

I want measure the linear acceleration (acceleration without gravity) but I don't know how to do it or if it is possible.

The device will be use to measure the pitch, roll, yam and linear acceleration in $x$,$y$,$z$ of a small boat.

Can some one help me please?

Comment: i want to remove the gravitacional acceleration from accelerometer readings

Comment: This is a common misconception regarding accelerometers. They do not and cannot sense gravity. They sense acceleration due to every force **except** gravity. An accelerometer at rest on a table registers an acceleration of 9.8 m/s^2 upward. How could this happen if accelerometers sensed gravity? Instead of removing gravitational acceleration, you need to add that unsensed downward acceleration due to gravitation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you simply calibrate the system while it is setting on a level table.  The reading is your local gravitational acceleration, which is taken as a constant.

You then enter this constant into the system, which is subtracted from the down axis.

It will certainly be more complex if you have to simultaneously correct multiple axes.

Comment: The system(boat) rotate. In other words.  The sensor is rotated when measure the acceleration.